# Nested Recyclerview Issues

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a fragment with parent RecyclerView and his child (the child is inner recyclerview). When I scroll to bottom (last data), and scroll it again to top, I found the problem. One of data is missing. When I try to scroll to bottom again and scroll to top, the data is random. Anyone can help me?

**HomeFragment**

```
    GridLayoutManager gl = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 1, 
    GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
    ParentAdapter adapter = new ParentAdapter(getContext(), parentList);
    rcvParent.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**OnBindViewHolder**

```
    holder.title.setText(parentList.get(position).getTitle());
    if (parentList.get(position).getProducts() != null) {
        for (ProductModel pm : parentList.get(position).getProducts()) {
            productList.add(pm);
        }
        GridLayoutManager childLayout = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 1, GridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        holder.childRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(childLayout);
        ChildAdapter ca = new ChildAdapter(mContext, productList);
        holder.childRecyclerView.setAdapter(ca);
    } else {
        holder.childRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

**ScreenShoot**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you scroll to bottom and again to top. the `OnBindViewHolder` method recall,
so the inner Recyclerview will set adapter another time.

It's better to use `NestedScrollView` as a parent of `fragment` instead of `RecyclerView`

you may face a problem that the recyclerview slow when scroll. use this code to solve it and enhance the performance.

```
 recycleview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
 ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recycleview, false);
 recycleview.setHasFixedSize(true);
 recycleview.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
 recycleview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
 recycleview.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
```

Now, you should use the code in the method `OnBindViewHolder` inside the `onCreateView` in your fragment to set the adapter for the inner recyclerView

tell me if you have any problem

Comment: I use recyclerview within recylerview cause the response is array within array sir, and it is dynamic, so I think should use inner recyclerview. any idea sir?

Comment: it works sir. I updated my inner recyclerview and set fragment layout to `NestedScrollView`, but the scroll is not smooth :(

Comment: yes, you should use these code

`recycleview.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
     ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(recycleview, false);
     recycleview.setHasFixedSize(true);
     recycleview.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
     recycleview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
     recycleview.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);`

Comment: I've write that code sir, but recyclerview scroll little by little :( I can't scroll to end with one scroll :(

Comment: I put the code in `OnBindViewHolder` sir. Is that right?

Comment: I'm sorry :( I made a mistake sir. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: How can we set the adapter for inner recyclerview from onCreateView of fragment? Can you provide any code or link for more reference  @MomenZaqout